# Where to find the 'views' settings from crm 2013 sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am having troubles finding the `views settings section` using `sql server`. What filtered views would I query to find these settings. I was told briefly to try looking in `FilteredUserQuery` but did not find all of the columns I am looking for. I have attached a screenshot for more clarification on which settings I am looking for. 
I am interested in these columns while using sql server. Please let me know if you have any questions or confusions with my questions. 


Here is a link to all of the different filtered views I have access to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531182.aspx

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks for the assitance!

Answer (score 3):

You need to look into `FilteredSavedQuery`, the entity `SavedQuery` holds the system views.

Comment: Thanks! I have been looking in the SavedQuery just recently, but I do not see the `type` column. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: type column is the "returnedtypecode" - good Q&A thanks guys :)